# Datagrid button tooltip binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a list of objects as the item source for the datagrid. I also have buttons with tooltips but I want the tooltips to be "localize-able"/dynamic. I don't want to explicitly add another property on the class of the objects (would be ugly) so instead, I want to create a string in the UserControl and do something like

```
public string ThisTag { get { return "someString"; } }
```

and on the xaml

```
<Button ...>
   <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
      <Tooltip Style={StaticResource ToolTipStyle} Tag={Binding Source=thisUserControl.ThisTag} />
...
```

the style

```
<Style x:Name="ToolTipStyle" TargetType="ToolTip">
   <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
               <Grid>
                  <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Foreground="{StaticResource AnotherResource}"></TextBlock>
...
```

1. Is that possible or is there a similar simple way to bind to a property?
2. What would be the proper syntax to bind to the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite make the Binding Path and ElementName style work so I settled to making a custom class like so

```
public class LocalizedDatagridButtonsTooltips
{
   public string TooltipOne { get { return SomeMethodToTranslate("This Phrase"); } }
   ...
}
```

create an instance of the class in the App.xaml (depends where the class is declared). "local" is declared on xaml.

```
<local:LocalizedDatagridButtonsTooltips x:Key="LocalizedTooltips"/>
```

Then setting the tag or whatever element that needs the string in the xaml (in my case, the Tag attribute needs the binding)

```
<Tooltip Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedTooltips}, Path=TooltipOne}" >
```

I got the solution from here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/using-static-resource-in-silverlight-3-application/

these solutions also works for 4-5 (I think SL 5 has the "AncestorType" accr. dbaseman).

Answer (score 0):

If the object is localizable resources, it might be best to use actual .ResX files.  See here for a good introduction on [how to use these within XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554%28v=vs.95%29) (basically, you reference the .ResX as a static XAML resource).

But if you really just want to bind to a code-behind property, this should also be possible.  It's a matter of setting the `Source` property correctly.  You can do this by referencing the root element's `DataContext`, ie:

```
<Button Content="button text">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.ThisTag,ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Where `LayoutRoot` is the name of the root element in the control/window/page.

<sub>1. Note that Silverlight 5 supports the use of `AncestorType` in relative bindings, but Silverlight 4 does not.


 2. Note also that you want to use `ToolTipService.ToolTip` (`Tag` is a way of embedding data in any XAML element, it doesn't actually display anything.)</sub>

Comment: the tooltip style is also customized that's why I had to use `<Button><Tooltipservice.Tooltip>...` so I can't use that binding directly. The style is being used by other tooltips too so I can't set the tag in the static resource.

Comment: @Bahamut I updated the syntax to use an inline Tooltip.  You want to set the actual display text of the tool tip, not the `Tag` property, right?

Comment: i forgot to include that the tag is being used in the style as the template's textblock's text so it is the Tag property that i need to bind. i've edited my post. i'll try it out too.

Comment: i did {Binding Path=DataContext.ThisTag,ElementName=LayoutRoot} but it's just blank. LayoutRoot is my root element int the xaml. does DataContext.ThisTag link the string ThisTag member of the user control? like 'public class MyUC : UserControl { public string ThisTag ... '

Comment: @Bahamut it links to the `ThisTag` member of the user control's `DataContext`.  So is its DataContext the code behind, or is it your model object?

Comment: i'm kind of confused with the term DataContext but basically the ThisTag string is a property of MyUC (my usecontrol).  Any other way I could declare the string and have a different syntax for the tag binding?

Comment: @Bahamut DataContext just means the source.  So if you write `{Binding Path=Something}`, then where will Silverlight look for the property `Something`?  That's the data context.  You need to set the `DataContext` of `LayoutRoot` to be your code-behind class; you can do that, for example, by using `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;` in the code-behind constructor.